# Material not changing Unity3d

Tags: unity, unityscript

I have a `MeshRenderer mr` public variable in `script1`. I dragged `mesh1` from the assets in the `mr` place in the inspector of `script1`. `mesh1` has a material `mat1`, I try to change this material to `mat2` using this `mr.sharedMaterial = mat2;` but the material doesn't change. It only changes the material in the assets but not the one in the hierarchy, so in the runtime nothing changes. Any advice please?

Comment: I followed your steps. It works well. This is the script I assigned. // public class Test : MonoBehaviour { public MeshRenderer mr; public Material m2; void Awake(){ mr.sharedMaterial = m2;}}

Comment: @JinbomHeo thanks for your comment. In my case the material in the assets is the one that is changed not the one is the hierarchy. Although the one in the hierarchy is a result of dragging and dropping the one in the assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I see.

I think your GameObject is a prefab which can not modified in the runtime.
So you can't apply the changes to other linked prefab objects in the runtime.

Only things that you can do is cloning and change the object's property respectively.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Could you please tell me how to clone and change the object's property? I will upvote your answer anyway =)

Comment: Ensure your MeshRenderer mr variable is pointing to the instance of the mesh renderer in the scene whose material you want to change, not to a prefab in your assets folder. You can create such an instance at runtime with the Instantiate() function.

Comment: @DMGregory is right. that's the cloning what I meant.

Comment: @DMGregory but when I do `Instantiate` from the MeshRenderer mr, I find a new mesh appearing in different location in the scene :/

Comment: @shepherd: right, because Instantiate creates a new instance of the object. If you already have an instance in the scene, you want to point at that one. Try naming the scene instance something different from the prefab - eg if your prefab is called "MyMesh", call the instance of MyMesh in your scene hierarchy "MyMeshInstance" - this will make it easier to tell which version your script variable is pointing at.

Comment: @DMGregory Okay, so if my prefab mesh is called `MyMesh` and the instance in the hierarchy is called `MyMeshInstance`. After using instantiate it creates another instance in the hierarachy called `MyMesh (clone)` which appears in the scene in different location than `MyMeshInstance`. And when I change the material of `MyMesh (clone)` it changes its material. But what I want to do is to change the material of `MyMeshInstance` not `MyMesh (clone)` nor `MyMesh`. Any advice please?

Comment: @shepherd If you already have an instance in your scene, you don't want to use Instantiate(). As I said above, that's only if you want to create a new instance at runtime. The change you need to make is to set your script variable mr to point at MyMeshInstance's MeshRenderer before trying to change its material. Comments aren't great for extended discussion, so if you have further trouble with this let's hop over to the chatroom.